# C# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#

```
List<String> employeeTimings;
    public string[] sTime = {"0000", "0030", "0100", "0130", "0200", "0230", "0300", "0330", "0400", "0430", "0500", "0530", "0600", "0630", "0700", "0730", "0800", "0830", "0900", "0930", "1000", "1030", "1100", "1130", "1200", 
                                 "1230", "1300", "1330", "1400", "1430", "1500", "1530", "1600", "1630", "1700", "1730", "1800", "1830", "1900", "1930", "2000", "2030", "2100", "2130", "2200", "2230", "2300", "2330"};

employeeTimings = new List<String>(sTime);
        int i=0;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Location", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Station", typeof(string)));

        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(employeeTimings[i], typeof(string));
            i++;
        }
        SchedulingTableDGV.DataSource = dt;
```

i get an error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." how can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add or remove from the collection you are iterating with a `foreach`. You need to perform adding or removing actions outside of the `foreach`.

```
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(employeeTimings[i], typeof(string)); // Problem.
        i++;
    }
```

Try this:

```
foreach (var timing in employeeTimings)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(timing, typeof(string));
}
```

Comment: can u write me an example how in this case?

Comment: You can use a for loop instead. `for(int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)`

Comment: @KennethTeo I've updated the answer with a possible alternative.

Comment: Without looking in the documentation; isn't `dt.Columns.AddRange(employeeTimings)` an opiton? Saves a `foreach`.

Comment: @Robill The documentation states that `AddRange` takes a `DataColumn[]`, which wouldn't work in this instance without a projection to create the column from the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a collection you are looping over with foreach. The solution in your case is pretty simple: Since you do not use `dc` inside the loop, why not use a normal for loop, like:

```
int length = dt.Columns.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(employeeTimings[i], typeof(string));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ you can do:

```
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().ToArray())
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(employeeTimings[i], typeof(string));
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the collection `dt.Columns` with the `Add` method while you are iterating over it:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(employeeTimings[i], typeof(string));
    i++;
}
```

Apart from *not* adding all timing strings this modifies the collection you are adding the columns to.

You should enumerate `employeeTimings` and add the columns like:

```
foreach(string s in employeeTimings)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(s, typeof(string));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your true intentions are to add the full employeeTimings list to the datatable columns
If this is right then you should loop on the list not on the columns

```
foreach (string s in employeeTimings) 
    dt.Columns.Add(s, typeof(string));
```